# Mac Excel conditional formating

Tags: microsoft-excel, mac, conditional-formatting

I want to format other cells in the row, where the last column has any data in it.  I  can get the last column to format by using the No blanks value but I cannot seem to get the other cells in the row to format (with fill).

Thanks!

Comment: Can you give us example of the desired output? Screenshot will help a lot in understanding what you really want.

Answer (score 0):

You'll be using a formula to determine which cells to format. Select all cells in the table > open Conditional Formatting > New Rule > change Style to *Classic* > *Use a formula to determine...* > enter the formula, for example `=IF($F2="",0,1)`, where `F` is the last column, and `2` is the first row in your selected range. The formula returns a 0 (formatting off) or 1 (formatting on). Like this:

[image: Excel for Mac 2011, Conditional Formatting with formula]